# Create a 301 redirect in Nginx that removes the `.html` ending from certain URL paths?

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

How to create a 301 redirect in Nginx that removes the `.html` ending from certain URLs?

I want to redirect all blog posts (301) to the same URL but without the `.html`.

E.g:

www.mydomain.com/blog/post1.html -> www.mydomain.com/blog/post1
www.mydomain.com/blog/post2.html -> www.mydomain.com/blog/post2

NOTE: I only want to remove the `html` from the www.mydomain.com/**blog**/ and leave the rest of the site paths as they are.

I managed to create a redirect for each post but surely there is a better way than this:

```
rewrite ^/blog/post1.html$ https://www.mydomain.co.uk/blog/post1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/(.*)\.html$ {
    return 301 https://$host/$1;
}
```

For only blog subpaths, this should work too:

```
location ~ ^/blog/(.*)\.html$ {
    return 301 https://$host/blog/$1;
}
```

Should do the trick.

~ Means regex.

^ and $ means beginning and end of regex.

(.*) means capture any number of indefined characters ( . means indefined * means any number)

and .html means ending by .html (wow)

And then you redirect it all to  https://$host/$1 where host is the host that came through, and $1 the captured string on the location regex.

Try it and let me know if it works in your environment.

Comment: Is this going to work only on the "/blog/" firectory?

Comment: No, it'll work on anything that ends with .html. For working only with /blog/, set ^/blog/(.*)\.html$ as the regex and return /blog/$1;